# Please someone tell me what is the mistake in my code and where i need to change it

Tags: php, sql

Am trying to fetch the data from the database into the WordPress plugin via SQL query. However, the loop is not working even though it is not showing any error. I tried many things on the internet but nothing of them is working. Here is my code below:-

Query Code:

```
<?php
        function vssp_settings() {
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM students_list" );
        foreach( $result as $print) {
           
?>
```

Showing the query result:

```
<td><?php echo $print["first_name"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $print["last_name"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $print["email"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $print["phone"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $print["address"];?></td>



<?php 
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Try `$print->...` instead of `$print["..."]`

Comment: This is not working

Comment: "This is not working" - It's a big NO NO here. Please be more specific. Are you sure for the table name ? Look strange for WP but maybe it's a custom table...

Comment: Please also change the title of your question. It should be a one short sentence that describe your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

do a var_dump($result);

and wrap the foreach in a condition like `if ($result) {...}`

See [get_results/](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/)

Try $print->... instead of $print["..."]

$output

Any of ARRAY_A | ARRAY_N | OBJECT | OBJECT_K constants.
With one of the first three, return an array of rows indexed from 0 by SQL result row number. Each row is an associative array (column => value, ...), a numerically indexed array (0 => value, ...), **or an object ( ->column = value )**, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The result is returned as object and you are using associative array to print so it will give error .Also you are not storing data in any variable inside a loop and not returning any value in the function. You can use the below code in your program:

```
function vssp_settings() {    
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM students_list");
    $data = '<table>';
    foreach ($result as $print) {
    $data .= '<tr><td>' . $print->first_name . '</td>';
    $data .= '<td>' . $print->last_name . '</td>';
    $data .= '<td>' . $print->email . '</td></tr>';
}
$data .= '</table>';
return $data;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I used your code but it didn't work, it is not even showing any error but the data is not printing there, can you please tell me something else which is helpful for me?

Comment: You need to echo the result  you are getting from the function vssp_settings()

Answer (score -1):

In WordPress, the get_results function returns an array of stdClass objects, not associative arrays, by default. Therefore, you need to access the elements as object properties using the arrow operator (->), rather than as array indices with square brackets ([]).

Ensure that your table name ('students_list') is correct and actually exists in your database. If the table name varies or relies on the WordPress prefix, you should employ $wpdb->prefix . 'your_table_name'.

As a precautionary measure, always check if `$result` is not empty before proceeding with a foreach loop to avoid potential issues.

To gain more detailed insight into potential errors, consider enabling debugging in WordPress. This can be done by adding the following line to your wp_config.php file: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`. This will provide a more comprehensive error output for diagnosis.